# How to shift data in turing machine?

Tags: finite-automata, turing-machines

While converting multitape turing machine into an equivalent singletape turing machine we have to shift the data and insert a blank to it.
    e.g :

```
Multitape = [1,2,3,4] [5,6,7,8] [9,10,11,12]
Equivalent singletape = [1,2,3,4,#,5,6,7,8,#,9,10,11,12]
consider this transition function in multitape turing machine :
[(q1,4) = (q2,4,R) and similar for others]
```

after this transition next element of tape1 is Blank
But in single tape

```
[(q1,4) = (q2,4,R) and for others]
```

After this transition next element of tape1 is # so we have to shift remaining data to insert a blank at this position.
How to do that? please give answers with respect to transition function.

Answer (score 0):

Your transition function only reads the first tape. A transition for the three.tape machien should look something like:

```
(q1,4,5,10) = (q2,4,R,6,L,11,R)
```

because you need instructions for all three tapes.

For the shifting: there is no better way than to shift all the data on one side of the current position one position by one. For example:

1. Mark current position
2. Run to the right-most symbol
3. Move right-most symbol one to the right
4. Move next symbol on the left one position to the right and so on until you reach the marked symbol